# ASP.NET on Ubuntu not finding library

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to run a project that uses EF, but a complaint arises from `dotnet`:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational**, Version=8.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
      File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
```

However, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll is right there in the same folder as the DLL of the project. How can it 'not find the file specified'?

Comment: Maybe is a different version

Comment: I copied the same file that my local dev machine is using, and checked file properties.. it's the right version. Also, it is marked executable with chmod..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution: delete bin and obj folders, rebuild the whole project, and deploy again. Now it works.. weird.

Comment: Let me guess: you updated from .net 7 to .net 8, or updated some package versions...

Comment: Nope that's the weird part. I've got no idea how it was the wrong version.